# How do I get rid of all these null values in Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I have created this Dashboard in Data Studio.  That data has three categories "All Food" which is a combination of "Fruits" and "Vegetables" and then "Fruits" and "Vegetables" have their own category.  I want to be able to have a control that lets you switch between the three categories and then a second control that will automatically update so you can pick the specific fruits and vegetables you want to see on the chart.  Here is the data I have:

[The data I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiCbL.jpg)

The problem is when you click on "Fruits" all the "Vegetables" become "null" so you get this "null" bar that I don't want.

[Dashboard Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AhXN.jpg)

Here is the code that I am using:

```
CASE Types
    WHEN "ALL FOOD" THEN "ALL FOOD"
    WHEN "Fruits" THEN Fruit 
    WHEN "Vegetables" THEN Vegatable 
END
```

Sorry if this is a bit of a noob question.

Here is a link to the dashboard I created so you can get an idea of what I am trying to do.

https://datastudio.google.com/s/iN-YdqlmD1w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it in your dashboard

```
CASE Parameter_Dummy
  WHEN "ALL FOOD" THEN COALESCE(Vegetable ,Fruit)
  WHEN "Vegetable" THEN Vegetable   
  WHEN "Fruit" THEN Fruit 
 END
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's also a way to fix this in the dataset. Instead of having a column for "fruit" (which is null for half the entries) and a column for "vegetables" (also null for half the entries), you could use a column for "type" and then indicate fruit or vegetable.

| Item | Type | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Plum | Fruit | 5 |
| Orange | Fruit | 5 |
| Strawberry | Fruit | 5 |
| Turnip | Vegetable | 4 |
| Carrot | Vegetable | 4 |
| Radish | Vegetable | 4 |

This only works if your food only has one type, but often that's the case.

When when you create your chart, you can use Type as a dimension. It will also let you easily sum across type without having to create a lot of calculated fields.